# Load gensim Word2Vec computed in Python 2, in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, gensim, word2vec

I have a gensim Word2Vec model computed in Python 2 like that:

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from gensim.models.word2vec import LineSentence

model = Word2Vec(LineSentence('enwiki.txt'), size=100, 
                 window=5, min_count=5, workers=15)
model.save('w2v.model')
```

However, I need to use it in Python 3. If I try to load it,

```
import gensim
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
model = Word2Vec.load('w2v.model')
```

it results in an error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf9 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I suppose the problem is in differences in encoding between Python2 and Python3. Also it seems like gensim is using pickle to save/load models.

Is there a way to set encoding/pickle options so that the model loads properly? Or maybe use some external tool to convert the model file?

Recomputing it in Python 3 is not an option: it takes way too much time.

Comment: For better python 2/3 interoperability an encoding should be specified, as noted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305790/pickle-incompatability-of-numpy-arrays-between-python-2-and-3). Since `gemsim` could use 2 methods to open a file, the smart_open library or an alternative method, the full traceback is required in finding a solution or workaround.

Comment: How did you solve it in the end? I tried the answer below, didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

This indeed looks like a bug somewhere, as noted by memoselyk, and can be fixed in a way described in a comment to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11314602/217088) answer.

So you have to add `encoding='latin1'` to a call to `_pickle.loads` in `gensim.utils.unpickle`, load the model in Python 3, then save it, and now you can revert this fix and load this new model in unmodified gensim with Python 3.