# Doc2Vec model Python 3 compatibility

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, gensim, doc2vec

I trained a doc2vec model with Python2 and I would like to use it in Python3.

When I try to load it in Python 3, I get :

```
Doc2Vec.load('my_doc2vec.pkl')

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It seems to be related to a pickle compatibility issue, which I tried to solve by doing :

```
with open('my_doc2vec.pkl', 'rb') as inf:
    data = pickle.load(inf)
data.save('my_doc2vec_python3.pkl')
```

Gensim saved other files which I renamed as well so they can be found when calling

```
de = Doc2Vec.load('my_doc2vec_python3.pkl')
```

The load() does not fail with UnicodeDecodeError but after the inference provides meaningless results.

I can't easily re-train it using Gensim in Python 3 as I used this model to create derived data from it, so I would have to re-run a long and complex pipeline.

How can I make the doc2vec model compatible with Python 3?

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33596082/load-gensim-word2vec-computed-in-python-2-in-python-3?rq=1) worked for me.

Here are the steps a bit more details :

1. download gensim source code, e.g clone from repo
2. in gensim/utils.py, edit the method unpickle to add the encoding parameter:

   ```
    return _pickle.loads(f.read(), encoding='latin1')
   ```
3. using Python 3 and the modified gensim, load the model:

   ```
   de = Doc2Vec.load('my_doc2vec.pkl')
   ```
4. save it:

   ```
   de.save('my_doc2vec_python3.pkl')
   ```

This model should be now loadable in Python 3 with unmodified gensim.