# About deep learning's theano tutorial?

Tags: deep-learning, theano

Look at http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/gettingstarted.html

I use python3.5 to write the code in windows 7

```
import pickle, gzip, numpy

f = gzip.open('mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb')
train_set, vaild_set, test_set = pickle.load(f)
f.close()
```

But I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\python_workspace\theanoTest\DataSet.py", line 7, in <module>
    train_set, vaild_set, test_set = pickle.load(f)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 614: ordinal not in range(128)
```

But in python3 the default encode is 'utf-8'

```
import sys
print(sys.getdefaultencoding())
```

So I don't know why does the error occur?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305790/pickle-incompatability-of-numpy-arrays-between-python-2-and-3.

Comment: Yeah, maybe incompatibility. @ThomasPinetz

Comment: There is an answer in that question. Have you tried their solution?