# How can I get the data from a .pkl file using Windows OS

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I have a .pkl file which loads perfectly in my MAC OS but it wont load in a windows machine. I am using python 3 on anaconda.
This is my code:

> data=pickle.load(open("ydata1.pkl",'rb'))

Error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 2295: ordinal not in range(128)

So I tried this:

> data=pickle.load(open("ydata1.pkl",'r'))

But I get an error saying :  a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `open()` with mode rb:

```
import pickle

with open('ydata1.pkl', 'rb') as p_f:
    data = pickle.load(p_f)
```

Taken from documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

> On Windows, 'b' appended to the mode opens the file in binary mode, so
>   there are also modes like 'rb', 'wb', and 'r+b'. Python on Windows
>   makes a distinction between text and binary files; the end-of-line
>   characters in text files are automatically altered slightly when data
>   is read or written. This behind-the-scenes modification to file data
>   is fine for ASCII text files, but it’ll corrupt binary data like that
>   in JPEG or EXE files. Be very careful to use binary mode when reading
>   and writing such files. On Unix, it doesn’t hurt to append a 'b' to
>   the mode, so you can use it platform-independently for all binary
>   files.

Also make sure you are not having Python 2 / Python 3 pickle compatibility issues: [Pickle incompatibility of numpy arrays between Python 2 and 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305790/pickle-incompatability-of-numpy-arrays-between-python-2-and-3)

Comment: there's a typo: data = pickle.load(p_f)