# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, pickle

Following is my code:

```
import gzip
import _pickle as cPickle

filename = "C:\\Users\\tende\\Desktop\\NLP\\hw2_package\\atis.small.pkl.gz"
f = gzip.open(filename,'rb')
train_set, valid_set, test_set, dicts = cPickle.load(f)
```

I am getting this error:

```
import gzip
import _pickle as cPickle

filename = "C:\\Users\\tende\\Desktop\\NLP\\hw2_package\\atis.small.pkl.gz"
f = gzip.open(filename,'rb')
train_set, valid_set, test_set, dicts = cPickle.load(f)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-27-aecb21b3784f>", line 6, in <module>
    train_set, valid_set, test_set, dicts = cPickle.load(f)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Please tell me where am I going wrong. I am using Python 3.6.2

Comment: Maybe check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305790/pickle-incompatability-of-numpy-arrays-between-python-2-and-3

Comment: @KaiserDandangi so it gives me the following error
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-39-3bb6f8df7336>", line 8, in <module>
    p = u.load()

  File "C:\Users\tende\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 1050, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)

KeyError: 31