# UnicodeDecodeError while using dill load

Tags: python, unicode, error-handling, python-3.7, dill

I am trying to load a model using dill.load but getting UnicodeDecodeError.

```
BASEDIR = './raw/data/'
modelfile = 'xyz.pkl'
model = dill.load(open('%s%s' % (BASEDIR, modelfile), 'rb'))
```

Error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc6 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried adding `encoding='utf-8'` based on other available answers but then I get a ValueError:

```
ValueError: binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument
```

The output of `locale` in my conda environment terminal:

```
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

I am using python 3.7

Comment: Was the `pkl` file created in Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: It was created in Python 2.7.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305790/pickle-incompatibility-of-numpy-arrays-between-python-2-and-3

Comment: As noted in the link above, this is common for pickling in 2.x and unpicking in 3.x.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Shall I delete my question?